# DB2 PL/SQL structure, begin atomic including with query

Tags: sql, plsql, db2

I'm trying to use db2 pl/sql script giving a template code.

```
--#set delimiter !

begin atomic

for S as
<query statement that finds quests, "swaps", with a donor/donation &     recipient pair>

do
<update statement that fixes Loot with the swap 'S'>;

end for;
-- handle each swap

end!
-- we're done once through
```

in my query statement i used something like this:

```
with
   t1 (args) as (
   ...
   )
   ...
   select ...
   where ... ;
```

in the update statement

```
update Loot set ... where ...
```

but the problem is, when i try to run the full sql code script on the database, I keep getting the message :

```
"An unexpected token "begin" was found following "<identifier>". 
Expected tokens may include: "USER". SQLSTATE=42601 DB21007E End of file 
reached while reading the command.
```

I want to know, how to use the proper syntax or format to include the "with queries" and also update statement to stop giving me the error. I have the "with query" working in a separate file, but when i combine both statements into the template, it would give me this error. Also as well, if I were to include triggers, which part of the code should i put it in. Thank you.

Comment: The error is on line 17 obviously.

Comment: Most of the code you provided does not look like valid SQL. I see lots of `...`

Comment: Why are you using a LOOP? Just update the table in a single UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might help.

```
CREATE TABLE EG(I INT, J INT)!
INSERT INTO EG VALUES (1,1),(2,3)!
begin
    for c as with w(i,u) as(values (2,5)) select i,u from w
    do
        update eg set j = j + c.u where i = c.i;
    end for;
end
!
```

If this does not help your problem, please post a version of your code that we can run and which returns the error message that you are struggling with.